# Proper logo/image sizing and positioning with css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position my logo onto the background image on my website but w/o success. The original size of my logo is 712x200 px. But I wanted it a bit smaller so I added height:140px and width:500px to my css (this is proportional to the original size of my logo).

However, the logo image is not resized (it doesn't become smaller as I defined in my css). Insted, it is cropped!? How come?

And how do I center the logo onto my background image, so that my loggo always appears in the very center of the screen (vertical and horizontal).

Here is my css code:

```
.logoimage{
    background: url("images/Logo.png") no-repeat scroll center;
    width: 500px;
    height: 140px;
}
```

Here is HTML:

```
<section id="home" class="photobg">
        <div class="inner">
                <div class="copy">
                    <h1 class="logoimage"></h1>


                </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Btw, I found some similar example of what I am trying to do here: http://milkandpixels.com/

So, basically I have a background image and I want to add the logo on top of it which should be centered all the time. Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm, does adding this style fix the issue?

```
.logoimage{
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Otherwise, let me know and I'll be happy to help further!

Comment: Yes, thanks! And how do I center it (both, horizontally and vertically)?

Comment: Hmm, then you could add another `center` to your background property, so it becomes `background: url("images/Logo.png") no-repeat scroll center center;` to vertically and horizontally center.

Comment: two center's didn't work. My logo still sticks to the center top :(

Comment: the div needs to be centered, or the background img within the div ?

Comment: I added HTML tag above. I would like to have my logo centered vertically and horizontally on my backgorund image. Thank you :)

Comment: I'm not sure what behaviour you're seeing; it seems to center the background image for me. Here's a link to a CodePen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/alxBA

Comment: Hmm. Your codepen looks good. But you have a background in the same class with logoimage. My background photo is inside #home and my logo is inside .logoimage. Not sure how to fix this. Should I add the logo into #home css???

Comment: Why all the nested DIVs with no content, and why an empty H1 for a logo (unless youre hiding H1 and swapping for a logo it's not SEO friendly, and still semantically debatable). Your HTML changes what you actually need.

Comment: Oh, are you looking to vertically center the `.logoimage` div itself inside its parent?

Comment: Yes, I thought to swap h1 for a logo but it's obviously not a good solution. What would you suggest me to do? I have 5 different sections in my webpage (Home, About, Services, Gallery, Contact). So all the nested div's have content in some sections.

Comment: Alright, I found the solution. Here it is: position:absolute;
 top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
 margin-top: -70px; /* Half the height */
    margin-left: -250px; /* Half the width */

Answer (score 1):

put the image in the image tag, add a class to the image tag. In the class put:

```
.logoimage{

    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use background-size:

```
 .logoimage{
    background: url("images/Logo.png") no-repeat scroll center;
    background-size: 500px 140px;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 0):

If none of the other answers work, you could always try and scale with
    `height: 50%`
    `width: 50%`

Answer (score 0):

```
This style might be useful:

.logoimage
{
background:url("flwr.gif");
background-size:140px 500px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding-top:40px;
}
```